# How to rotate images saved in Google Drive?

Tags: image, google-chrome, google-drive-api, drive

I often upload the images in Gdrive taken from my camera, some images are in different orientation. While viewing an image in drive, how to rotate it, as there is no option provided by Google to rotate the image.

Comment: duplicate: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52073/how-to-rotate-images-saved-in-google-drive

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/c8tR5B5oSnk/RRc5EIm88lgJ), you can't rotate in Google Drive.

However, there is another workaround on how to do this in a native way.

**See [How to rotate images saved in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52073/how-to-rotate-images-saved-in-google-drive)**

> There is a native way: access [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/).
>
> [First you need to enable google drive pictures as shown here.](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)
>   Please once in that page, read below "View & edit photos stored in
>   Google Drive using Google Photos"
>
> Then select the image, and either press shift+r, or in the top right
>   corner choose "more options"> Rotate
>
> Edit: Please note, according to [this official help page:](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6156103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)
>
> > If you edit photos in Google Photos, those changes will not show in
> >     Google Drive.
>
> That means you have to manually move the edited photos in google
>   photos to the desired goal location, such as google drive.

Answer (score -1):

If the uploaded orientation of the photo is wrong due to oversight while uploading, I have found it much easier to orient the photos right in the original and upload again as version two.  It takes much less time than editing individually in a online photo editor